# remove attribute in json that contain multivalue in asp.net c# before show it in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview, multivalue

I'm newbie in asp.net c# . Iwant to show the json data into table with gridview .I have json data with this format :

```
[{
    "reviewerID": "A1YS9MDZP93857",
    "asin": "0006428320",
    "reviewerName": "John Taylor",
    "helpful": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "reviewText": "last movement of sonata #6 is missing. What should one expect?",
    "overall": 3,
    "summary": "Parts missing",
    "unixReviewTime": 1394496000,
    "reviewTime": "03 11, 2014"
},
{
    "reviewerID": "A3TS466QBAWB9D",
    "asin": "0014072149",
    "reviewerName": "Silver Pencil",
    "helpful": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "reviewText": "If you are a serious violin student on a budget, this edition has it all",
    "overall": 5,
    "summary": "Perform it with a friend, today!",
    "unixReviewTime": 1370476800,
    "reviewTime": "06 6, 2013"
}]
```

to show that into gridview I use the following code (using Json.net library)

```
JsonString = TextBox1.Text;
       dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString, (typeof(DataTable)));
       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
```

the problem is gridview cannot show the data, and it's work if I remove **"helpfull"** attribute like this one by one :

```
{
"reviewerID": "A1YS9MDZP93857",
"asin": "0006428320",
"reviewerName": "John Taylor",
"reviewText": "The portfolio is fine except for the fact that the last movement of sonata #6 is missing. What should one expect?",
"overall": 3,
"summary": "Parts missing",
"unixReviewTime": 1394496000,
"reviewTime": "03 11, 2014"}
```

I don't know code how to remove it , Since i have large json data, i'ts difficult and wasting time to remove it manually. Any idea?

Comment: Why dont you convert it on js side? it would be much easier

Comment: thanks.Actually I just tried using many online json tool, but it's just allow me to remove it one by one, and another remove algrthm i've used , it's work, but not for multivalue attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Json.NET, if you want to remove unwanted properties before deserializing to `DataTable`, you can convert to an intermediate [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchical representation, then [remove](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Remove.htm) properties with unwanted names.  After this is done, you can deserialize to your final `DataTable` class with [`JToken.ToObject<T>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm).

To parse to a `JToken`, do:

```
        var obj = JToken.Parse(JsonString);
```

Then to remove unwanted properties by name:

```
        var unwanteds = new HashSet<string>(new[] 
        {
            "helpful"
        });
        foreach (var property in obj.Children().SelectMany(o => o.OfType<JProperty>()).Where(p => unwanteds.Contains(p.Name)).ToList())
        {
            property.Remove();
        }
```

Or, to remove all *except* wanted properties, by name:

```
        var keepers = new HashSet<string>(new[]
        {
            "reviewerID",
            "asin",
            "reviewerName",
            "reviewText",
            "overall",
            "summary",
            "unixReviewTime",
            "reviewTime",
        });
        foreach (var property in obj.Children().SelectMany(o => o.OfType<JProperty>()).Where(p => !keepers.Contains(p.Name)).ToList())
        {
            property.Remove();
        }
```

Finally, deserialize:

```
        var dt = obj.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Comment: Hi @dbc , thanks for the answer, can u tell me what did obj.SelectTokens("[*]")

Comment: @Ana - it lets you do wildcard searches. See [Querying JSON with JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) and [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Comment: can u tell me parameter in this method :
`obj.SelectTokens("[*]")` , I have tried the source code you gave (remove all except wanted properties), when run occurred exception : 
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: *

Comment: @Ana - what version of Json.NET are you using?  JSONPath support was added to [6.0 Release 1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support).

Comment: Whoa, I use Json.NET 5.0.6, I should update it first,.

Comment: @Ana - you might want to, there are probably bugs that have been fixed.  I can update the answer though.

Comment: @Ana - [`Children()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Children.htm) should do the same thing given that the root container is an array.  Answer updated.

Comment: yeah @dbc, after update json.net now new exception occured for Binding data to gridview
` var dt = obj.ToObject<DataTable>();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();`

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

Comment: @Ana - Maybe I misunderstood your precise problem -- did you want to remove the `helpful` property, or remove *all except* the `helpful` property?  In my answer I remove everything except `helpful`.

Comment: yes i need to remove helpful property (also it's value), please help

Comment: @Ana - answer updated by exchanging the contents of `unwanteds` and `keepers`